# Bitcoin transaction validation is not based on a static pattern, but instead is achieved through the execution of a scripting language

Tags: transactions, transaction-verification

What is static pattern and why it is not used in transaction validation  and why execution pattern is used through the scripting language i am a bit confused need a clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> **What is static pattern**

Each type of Bitcoin transaction has a certain pattern, the chunk of data can be broken down into pieces. The size, form and sequence of these these pieces are a pattern. Static means this pattern does not change from one transaction to another of the same type.  All transactions of the same type have the same pattern.

> **why it is not used in transaction validation**

It is.

> **why execution pattern is used through the scripting language**

Bitcoin's scripting language allows for flexibility in creating new types of transactions. Each different script is a rule that specifies how the network can recognise that someone is entitled to spend money in a transaction output. Nodes check that scripts are well-formed and that people spending outputs have provided data that satisfies that script (e.g. proving they know a secret number called a private-key). All this checking is called validation (which is very different from confirmation - people sometimes get confused about this).